# d3 v3 - sync brush zoom and scroll zoom

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, semantic-zoom

I'm trying to add brush zoom and scroll zoom within the same chart but for it's getting a bit difficult to sync both which depend on X and Y both. How do I compute the translate and scale values based on the axes domains?

Here's a sample chart I've written down to test the same:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var fullX = x.copy();
var fullY = y.copy();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.close);
    });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
    
 var g = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var data = [{
    date: "1-May-12",
    close: "58.13"
}, {
    date: "30-Apr-12",
    close: "53.98"
}, {
    date: "27-Apr-12",
    close: "67.00"
}, {
    date: "26-Apr-12",
    close: "89.70"
}, {
    date: "25-Apr-12",
    close: "99.00"
}];

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.date;
    }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.close;
    })]);


var gBrush = g.append('g').classed('brush', true);

var gAxisX = g.append("g") // Add the X Axis
.attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    
var gAxisY = g.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
.attr("class", "y axis");

function drawAxes() {
  gAxisX.call(xAxis);
  gAxisY.call(yAxis);
}

drawAxes();

var brushing = false;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 10000])
.on('zoom', function () {

  if(brushing && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === 'mousemove' && d3.event.sourceEvent.which !== 2) return ;

  drawAxes();
});
svg.call(zoom);

var brush = d3.svg.brush().x(x).y(y)
.on('brushstart', function () {
  d3.select(this).select('rect.extent').style('display', null);
})
.on('brush', function () {
    brushing = true;
})
.on('brushend', function () {
  brushing = false;
  d3.select(this).select('rect.extent').style('display', 'none');
  
  var extent = brush.extent();
  
  x.domain([extent[0][0], extent[1][0]]);
  y.domain([extent[0][1], extent[1][1]]);

    var sx = x.domain(), sy = y.domain();

  var k = Math.min((x.range()[1]-x.range()[0]) / (fullX(sx[1]) - fullX(sx[0])), (y.range()[1]-y.range()[0]) / (fullY(sy[1]) - fullY(sy[0]))),
      tx = fullX.range()[0] - fullX(sx[0]) * k,
      ty = fullY.range()[0] - fullY(sy[0]) * k;

   // zoom.translate([tx, ty]).scale(k);

 // zoom.x(sy).y(sy); - I don't want to do this to respect scaleExtent to original domains

  drawAxes();
});

gBrush.call(brush);

d3.select('#autofit').on('click', function () {
// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.date;
    }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.close;
    })]);
    drawAxes();
})
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
rect.extent {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


<button id='autofit'>
Autofit
</button>
```

Yes, there are a few examples related to the same but in v4 and I'm trying to get this done in v3.

Reference 1: [D3.js: Combining Zoom/Brush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080833/d3-js-combining-zoom-brush) (v4)

Reference 2: http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9689303 (problem with this is that zoom's x is scaled to the new brushed zoom which messes up the scaleExtent and I would like to restrict the zooming to the original domains)

The lines that I'm struggling with are:

```
 var k = Math.min((x.range()[1]-x.range()[0]) / (fullX(sx[1]) - fullX(sx[0])), (y.range()[1]-y.range()[0]) / (fullY(sy[1]) - fullY(sy[0]))),
  tx = fullX.range()[0] - fullX(sx[0]) * k,
  ty = fullY.range()[0] - fullY(sy[0]) * k;
```

// zoom.translate([tx, ty]).scale(k);

inside the **brushed function**.

Basically trying to compute the translate and scale based on the new domains. The logic used there works for x if the **k** is computed based on x.range() and works for y if **k** is computed based on y.range() BUT to make them both work together seems to be a struggle (Math.min didn't work). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no way to transform both X and Y at the same time as mentioned by Mike here: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/48

P.S. If you have a restricted zoom i.e. either horizontal or vertical, then you can make both the zoom functions work together by applying appropriate scales.

For example for X translation and scale:

```
k_x = (x.range()[1]-x.range()[0]) / (fullX(sx[1]) - fullX(sx[0])); 
t_x = fullX.range()[0] - fullX(sx[0]) * k_x
```

While for Y axes translation and scale,

```
 k_y = (y.range()[1]-y.range()[0]) / (fullY(sy[1]) - fullY(sy[0])));
 ty = fullY.range()[0] - fullY(sy[0]) * k_y;
```

There are a couple of workarounds mentioned within this issue which I'll be looking into and if anything works out smooth, I'll post it on here.